# Is it possible to replace a DLL with a dummy implimentation but using the original LIB file

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

we have a project which uses a Win32 DLL and the project is built using the LIB file relevant to that DLL.But as a new requirement we were asked to create a new dummy DLL but we have to use the original LIB file.

What i would like to know is whether this is practical or whether one must create a new LIB file as well.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly possible to do what you describe, although somewhat pointless. Once you've made it as far as making the dummy DLL, a new import library .lib will be generated.

So long as the DLL that you create uses functions with the same exported name or ordinal (depending on how you export the functions), and has functions with the same interface, then what you are attempting will work.

It's common to make a dummy DLL in order to generate a .lib file. This would be done if the DLL was created by tooling that does not output .lib files.

Comment: Yes its more of a managerial issue rather than technical issue.For some reason decided from the top management we can only touch some part of the code base.thus unfortunately it seems we can not touch the lib file

Comment: From a technical standpoint, this is no different to DLL hijacking.  So we know it works, even if we might wish it didn't. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you would have to re-use, or reverse-engineer, the original .DEF file so as to ensure that the same import ordinals are used, if there are any.

Comment: Only necessary if the .lib file uses ordinals